# XSLT position() function not working as expected in Two Step View

Tags: html, xml, xslt, poeaa

While trying to implement the pattern "Two Step View" as described by Martin Fowler, I had some problems getting the alternate-row colouring of the HTML table to work.  This uses the XSLT `position()` function.  You can see the XSLT template for `table/row` below.  However, in the output, the `bgcolor` attribute of the `tr` element is always `"linen"`, indicating that the value of `position()` is not changing as we iterate over `table/row` elements.  Why would this be?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="screen">
    <html>
      <body bgcolor="white">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </h1>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="field">
    <p><b><xsl:value-of select="@label"/>: </b><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="table">
    <table><xsl:apply-templates/></table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="table/row">
    <xsl:variable name="bgcolor">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="(position() mod 2) = 0">linen</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>white</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <tr bgcolor="{$bgcolor}"><xsl:apply-templates/></tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="table/row/cell">
    <td><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<screen>
  <title>Dissociation</title>
  <field label="Artist">Dillinger Escape Plan</field>
  <table>
    <row>
      <cell>Limerent Death</cell>
      <cell>4:06</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell>Symptom Of Terminal Illness</cell>
      <cell>4:03</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell>Wanting Not So Much To As To</cell>
      <cell>5:23</cell>
    </row>
  </table>
</screen>
```

Output HTML:

```
<html><body bgcolor="white">
  <h1>Dissociation</h1>
  <p><b>Artist: </b>Dillinger Escape Plan</p>
  <table>
    <tr bgcolor="linen">
      <td>Limerent Death</td>
      <td>4:06</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="linen">
      <td>Symptom Of Terminal Illness</td>
      <td>4:03</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="linen">
      <td>Wanting Not So Much To As To</td>
      <td>5:23</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<table><xsl:apply-templates/></table>` to `<table><xsl:apply-templates select="row"/></table>` or use `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` or at least `<xsl:strip-space elements="table"/>`. Currently you are processing all child nodes, including white space text nodes, that way your attempt using `position()` fails.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  But, I don't really understand why, surely `<xsl:template match="table/row">` would prevent the `position()` test from evaluating on non-row elements?  What's the difference between that use of `match` (which doesn't work), and the use of `select=` (which does work)?

Comment: With `<xsl:apply-templates/>` (as it is a shorthand for `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>`) you select all child nodes for processing and that way you have a different node-set (XSLT 1.0) or sequence (XSLT 2.0) being processed compared to `<xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>`. Inside all child nodes a certain `row` element has a different position compared to looking only at the `row` elements, in particular with formatted XML where there are white space text nodes between element nodes. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Applying-Template-Rules for details.

Comment: Respectively https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#applying-templates saying "The rule that matches the Nth node in the sorted sequence is evaluated with that node as the context item, with N as the context position, and with the length of the sorted sequence as the context size."